# No virtual method getLongVersionCode()J when getting version code

Tags: android, nosuchmethoderror

According google suggestion i am using `getLongVersionCode` to get version code like this:

```
private long getCurrentCode() {
    try {
        return context.getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).getLongVersionCode();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

but when i run my app, my app force closed and i got this error:

```
Process: com.xxxxx.debug, PID: 25754
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getLongVersionCode()J in class Landroid/content/pm/PackageInfo; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.content.pm.PackageInfo' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
        at com.xxxxx.common.ApplicationUpdateTask.getCurrentCode(ApplicationUpdateTask.java:329)
        at com.xxxxx.common.ApplicationUpdateTask.<init>(ApplicationUpdateTask.java:84)
```

So i decided to use:

```
String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
```

but now this commend return `-1` !!!!!

This is my gradle config:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 66
        versionName '2.0.66'
        applicationId 'com.xxxxxx.yyyyy'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `long getLongVersionCode()` was added to Android in version 28; see [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#getLongVersionCode())

It is clearly present in the APIs you are compiling against, otherwise you would get a compilation error.

But the exception says that it is not present at runtime, so you must have been running on an older platform.

I don't know what you mean when you say that you used this:

```
String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
```

The version name and code are different things.  Maybe you used `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE`?

And I don't know what you mean by this:

> but now this commend return -1 !!!!!

My guess is that there is something wrong with way you are using the version name or code attributes.  But that's just a guess.  You haven't shown us the code.

---

The other thing to note is that prior to API version 28, you could use the `PackageInfo.versionCode` attribute ([javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#versionCode)).  This was deprecated in API version 28.  So it should be possible to use reflection to call the `getLongVersionCode()` method if available, and fall back to using reflection to access the `versionCode` attribute.  (Or test the value of `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` at runtime to find out what API version the platform supports.)

Or you could just set the minimum supported Android version for your app to 28.

Comment: Ops, sorry i used `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE` ,It was may mistake

Answer (score 6):

I recommend you to use PackageInfoCompat:

```
PackageInfoCompat.getLongVersionCode();
```

It automatically checks the sdk version greater than 28 and returns appropriately versionCode or LongVersionCode. It is included in androidx.

Comment: I had to call it like this `PackageInfoCompat.getLongVersionCode(getPackageInfo())` where `getPackageInfo()` is my own function that essentially returns `applicationContext!!.packageManager.getPackageInfo(applicationContext!!.packageName, 0)`.  I'm using Kotlin, compileSdkVersion 29, minSdkVersion 23, targetSdkVersion 29.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note for those looking here.  Although this says that it was added in 28, I can say for sure it does not work in Android 8.1.  Same runtime error.  Changing my code to check for Android.os.Build.VERSION_SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P before trying to use getLongVersionCode() avoided the error.